# webstorm 8, how to get rid of warning message

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, webstorm

I kept getting this warning message "invalid number of argument, expected 2. but my code is fine. i can run my application.  i can ignore them, but it just bothers me. how do i get rid of them?

it seems like webstorm didn't know that app.use can also take only one argument. This is what I tried. javascript -> libraries, I added node modules there. still doesn't work.

pic is very small, so i paste my coffeescript codes below.

```
app.use favicon()
app.use logger 'dev'
app.use bodyParser.json()
app.use bodyParser.urlencoded()
app.use cookieParser()
app.use express.static path.join __dirname, 'app/public'
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Same here. Looks like WebStorm just goes through the source code and get the argument list, and brings warning if any missed parameters we specified even though in JavaScript they will be as `undefined`. What I did is to pass many `undefined` and hopefully WebStorm and fix it in the next update.

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem: in the express docs favicon is expected to receive 2 params.. even though options shoule likely be an optional parm.

you can either ignore the warning, or pass an empty `{}` as the 2nd param

```
 /**
  * Serves the favicon located by the given `path`.
  *
  * @public
  * @param {String|Buffer} path
  * @param {Object} options
  * @return {Function} middleware
  */

  module.exports = function favicon(path, options){
```

Answer (score -1):

WebStorm just uses the JSDoc to determine the number of parameters. And here is what the use function definition looks like (node_modules\express\lib\application.js):

```
/**
* Proxy connect#use() to apply settings to
* mounted applications.
*
* @param {String|Function|Server} route
* @param {Function|Server} fn
* @return {app} for chaining
* @api public
*/
app.use = function(route, fn){...}
```

as you can see, it takes exactly 2 params... None of them is marked as optional

As a workaround I'd suggest disabling the 'Node.js Dependencies' library and using the express-DefinitelyTypes instead as suggested in http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-6667#comment=27-589563

Comment: his IDE is complaining about the `favicon` function not the `app.use` function